# Azure Bot - having issues with formatting data from json payload into adaptive cards

Tags: json, azure, parsing, bots, adaptive-cards

I am currently working on a bot that triggers a HTTP requrest to a remote endpoint. That endpoint processes generic requests. The payload is dynamic depending on a request type. Examples of these requests are:

- getting user's AD information vs setting a AD or AzureAD group info vs reaching out to another API

Output example below. Also, Once that(those) special characters are removed, I need to iterate through each of the populated items only and render them in an adaptive card

```
{
  "lgType": "Activity",
  "text": [
    {
      "GivenName": "john",
      "Surname": "doe",
      "UserPrincipalName": "jdoe@domain.com",
      "Enabled": true,
      "SamAccountName": "jdoe",
      "SID": {
        "BinaryLength": 28,
        "AccountDomainSid": {
          "BinaryLength": 24,
          "AccountDomainSid": {
            "BinaryLength": 24,
            "AccountDomainSid": {
              "BinaryLength": 24,
              "AccountDomainSid": "S-2-2-17-438902509-970237201-892232075",
              "Value": "S-2-2-17-438902509-970237201-892232075"
            },
            "Value": "S-2-2-17-438902509-970237201-892232075"
          },
          "Value": "S-2-2-17-438902509-970237201-892232075"
        },
        "Value": "S-2-2-17-438902509-970237201-892232075"
      },
      "DistinguishedName": "CN=Doe\, John,OU=HQ,DC=domain,DC=com",
      "Name": "Doe, John",
      "ObjectClass": "user",
      "ObjectGuid": "39e4466a-3644-40ce-2317-c0d3a6c45f4mc0",
      "PropertyNames": [
        "DistinguishedName",
        "Enabled",
        "GivenName",
        "Name",
        "ObjectClass",
        "ObjectGUID",
        "SamAccountName",
        "SID",
        "Surname",
        "UserPrincipalName"
      ],
      "AddedProperties": [],
      "RemovedProperties": [],
      "ModifiedProperties": [],
      "PropertyCount": 10,
      "ObjectGUID": "39e4466a-3644-40ce-2317-c0d3a6c45f4mc0"
    }
  ]
}
```

**For removing the character:**

I have tried many variations of this

- @"replace('${dialog.api_response}', '\', '')"
- @"replace('${dialog.api_response.text}', '\', '')"

For iterating through that json payload:

```
    {
      ${generateList()}
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "text": foreach(json("${dialog.api_response.text}"), x, concat(x.key, ':', x.value))
      "isSubtle": false
    }
```

Any help, assistance, and guidance will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here’s an example of how you can remove the backslash character from a string:

```
const stringWithBackslash = "CN=Doe\\, John,OU=HQ,DC=domain,DC=com";
const stringWithoutBackslash = stringWithBackslash.replace(/\\/g, "");
console.log(stringWithoutBackslash); // Output: "CN=Doe, John,OU=HQ,DC=domain,DC=com"
```

Comment: thank you, Ramprasad, for my apologies for the delayed response. I forgot to mention that I'm doing this in Composer as I am not a developer :/